# Migrating a GIT Repository to the Cloud

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am currently working in a repository that is stored on our locally hosted network at:
`http://git.**company**.internal/Development/repo.git`

The company is in the process of moving everything to the cloud instead of hosting everything ourselves. It seems like a convenient time to move the GIT repository to the cloud as well. It's been a while since I've done much besides pushing, pulling, and merging to the repo - so I don't want to mess this up. I want to create a separate repo stored based in the cloud and change my local directory to point to the new repo instead of the old one.

As I said, I am fuzzy on the GIT commands to do this - so it may just be simple.

My idea is - I need to fork the current repository, cd into a directory that is stored on the cloud, clone(?) that repository, and then pointing my working directory to the new one is a mystery to me.

I'm sorry if this is confusing, my understanding of GIT is lackluster. I can provide clarification on what I am looking for if this isn't clear.

Comment: Normally any "cloud" git provides an service to migrate existing git repositories to theirs. At least in Bitbucket you can just "import repository"

To change the remote repository just edit the git config in .git folder on your local clone

from git@localcompany to git@bitbucket if you worked with ssh just add the ssh keys to the new bitbucket repository.

Comment: Why the need to fork your local working directory? Couldn't you just add a new remote and push to the new git host?

Comment: That is also possible.

Comment: @FabianBörner The cloud service provider isn't specifically for git, the main purpose is supposed to just be a bulk storage solution. So can I just point to a folder from a network drive that is being stored on the cloud and make that the remote?

Comment: Git is much more complex than a file storage and not supposed to work that way

Comment: If you can start your own git repo there and configure ssh its possible

Comment: I understand that I just don't understand how to change where a repo's files are stored - migrating from one server to another.

Comment: So cd into the desired directory and do a git clone command of the repo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208917/discussion-between-fabian-borner-and-joey-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Github:

1. Create new repository in Github and don't create a readme file.
2. Clone the mentioned repository from your server to your local machine.
3. `git remote add origin <url>` (url of the new github repo)
4. `git push origin master`

Note: you shouldn't commit because you probably already have commits in this repository, just add a new remote I called it origin and push it to the Github server

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you're trying to do.

> The company is in the process of moving everything to the cloud instead of hosting everything ourselves. It seems like a convenient time to move the GIT repository to the cloud as well

Are you moving the repo to the cloud, or it done for you?
Where is your git repo now? Surely you don't have it on your local drive only, as it for the most part defeats the purpose of git...

- If someone else is moving your git repo, all you have to do is add a new remote to your current git repo (and may be remove the existing one).
  You can add it via a cli:

  ```
  $ git remote add <name> <url>
  ```

  You can read the rest here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote
- If you're the one who's moving the repo, then you need to do the following:

  1. create a repo on your cloud (be that GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab etc)
  2. add a new remote to your existing repo pointing to the new repo
  3. switch to the `master` (or whatever main branch you have) locally
  4. push to the new remote:

  ```
  $ git push <new remote name> master
  ```

  5. (optionally) remove the original remote

From that point onwards, just do what you've been doing before, just push to and fetch from the new remote.

---

(Shameless plug) You can also you [Git Extensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases) to help you visualise your repos and save you fro remembering all these git commands.